# How can I hide the sitemap from public view?

Tags: sitemap

do you know how can I hide the sitemap just from the public view? 
cheers

Answer (score 3):

Just give your sitemap a name that people aren't going to guess EVER, rather than `sitemap.xml`

From a post on a blog:

> For what it's worth I give my sitemap a name that no-one's going to be
>   able to guess, rather than sitemap.xml, then just submit it to the
>   three big SEs.

It's as simple as that. Hope it helps.